# Using an R variable before the code chunk in which the variable was created

Tags: r, knitr

I would like to include an R calculation in the abstract. The R calculation is at the bottom of document, so when I compile the `Rnw` file I get an error.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
    This paper... and we got a mean of \Sexpr{mean.data}.
\end{abstract}

<<>>=
data <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
mean.data <- mean(data)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: for now, knitr executes code chunks and inline expressions in a linear fashion, so you cannot use "future" objects; but I might provide something in the future to allow you to load objects from the future cache if the cache database exists

Comment: I have provided an example below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58104427/559676

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the computations to appear after the abstract,
you can save the result to a file, and load it in the abstract.
You have to compile the LaTeX file twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
 This paper... and we got a mean of \Sexpr{load("a.RData"); mean.data}.
\end{abstract}

<<Computations>>=
data <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
mean.data <- mean(data)
save(mean.data, file="a.RData")
@

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well you *obviously* need to move the *definition of something being used* before it is being used, not after. So try this instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
data <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
mean.data <- mean(data)
@

\begin{abstract}
    This paper... and we got a mean of \Sexpr{mean.data}.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Chunks can occur just about everywhere, including *before* `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Yes, but for something like a summary/abstract, it's useful functionality to be able to load data from "future" chunks. Yihui's reply has a means to cache results which is useful in this context.

Comment: So does @Vincent's which came _about six years earlier_ and neither of those falsify my claim that you need something computed before you use it.  There are simply three different ways to go about it.  <Shrug>.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `knitr::load_cache()` function as demonstrated in the example `114-load-cache.Rmd` in the repo https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples. Below is how to use the function in your case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This paper... and we got a mean of \Sexpr{knitr::load_cache('test-a', 'mean.data')}.
\end{abstract}

<<test-a, cache=TRUE>>=
data <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
mean.data <- mean(data)
@

\end{document}
```

The first time when you compile this document, `mean.data` won't be available, but it will be read from the cache when you recompile the document.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach if you are using LaTeX is to rearrange the order of the output in the LaTeX processing stage. I asked a [somewhat similar question on the TeX stack exchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40548/10615).

The approach uses the `filecontents` (LaTeX) package to store part of the output and then replay it later. In this approach, your abstract would actually be defined at the end of the document, but everything above it would be stored in a file and then reinserted after the abstract during the LaTeX processing step.