# How to write an article with an abstract referencing data that has not yet been calculated?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

UPDATE: Seems like my question is actually a very near duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581027/using-an-r-calculation-in-an-article-abstract)
and according to that thread, there is currently no "easy" solution.  However, that question is over a year old now, and the time may have changed (one can hope!).

My original question follows:

---

I'm thinking that I need some kind of mechanism to re-order the text and or `R` chunks in the document as it is being knit.  What I want to be able to do is to write an "article" style document with an abstract and summary at the beginning, before I get into any `R` code, but that contains "forward"-references to things that will be calculated in the `R` code.

So my exec summary at the beginning might be

```
We found a `r final_correlation/100`% correlation between x and y...
```

but "final_correlation" will be calculated at the back end of the document as I go through all of the steps of the reproducible research.

Indeed, when I read about reproducible research, I often see comments that the documentation can often be better presented out-of programming sequence.

I believe that in other literate programming frameworks the chunks can be tangled into a different order from that in which they were presented.  How can I achieve that in `knitr`?  Or is there some other completely different workflow or pattern I could adopt to achieve the outcome I want?

Comment: One possibility: Separate the data processing into an R script, source that R script at the start of your document, and all the data would be available to you.

Comment: another option is to use `brew` to preprocess the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to define the order to evaluate all the code chunks in knitr at the moment. One idea I can think of is to write the abstract in the end of the article, and include it in the beginning. An outline:

- article.Rmd
- abstract.Rmd

In `article.Rmd`:

````
Title.

Author.

Abstract.

```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
if (file.exists('abstract.md')) {
  cat(readLines('abstract.md'), sep = '\n')
} else {
  cat('Abstract not ready yet.')
}
```

More code chunks.

```{r}
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10)
final_correlation <- cor(x, y)
```

Body.

```{r include=FALSE}
knitr::knit('abstract.Rmd')  # generates abstract.md
```
````

In `abstract.Rmd`:

```
We found a `r final_correlation/100`% correlation between x and y...
```

Comment: I get that this is a great way for keeping the DRY principle in the current way that `knitr` works.  I had been hoping for a one-file solution.  And I have my answer for today, thank you!